# If statement inside click function doesn't work as expected after the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

check the code below

When I click on the `span` **for the first time**, it triggers `markStarted` function and `fa` icon and `data-aevent` are updated successfully. And I get `started` in dev console.

When I click it again **(without page reload)** `markFinished` is not triggered. And I still get 'started' in console.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<span class="label label-info check " data-id="4" data-aevent="finish"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></span>
```

markStarted, markFinished

```
var markStarted = function(task){
  task.find('i').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-check');
  var nextstate = "finish";
  task.data("data-aevent", nextstate);
  console.log("started");
}
var markFinished = function(task){
  task.fadeOut();
  console.log("finished");
}
```

on click function

```
$(function() {
    $(".check").on("click", function() {
      var task = $(this);
      var task_id = task.data("id")
      var aevent = task.data("aevent");

      if (aevent == "start"){
        markStarted(task);
      }else {
        markFinished(task);
      }

    });
  });
```

Comment: try changing `task.attr("data-aevent", nextstate)` to `task.data("aevent", nextstate)`.

Comment: I see, please update the code so others won't get confused with it :)

Comment: @dMd, there's no difference

Comment: yeah u're right, i was importing in the older jquery 1.4.2 haha

Comment: @railsr see Joah's answer.. thats what you're doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `markStarted`, you're calling `task.data("data-aevent ...`, where you need to be calling `task.data("aevent" ...`

Comment: thanks but `task.data("aevent", "eewew");` doesn't update `data-aevent' inside the span.

Comment: the problem was exactly in using `data-` part of `data-aevent`. Thanks